# C program- reading doubles into a text file from directory, program recognizes as zero values

Tags: c, file, text, directory, double

I'm trying to read doubles from multiple text files in a directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{

DIR *ptr;
double variable;
int n, i;
FILE *f, *fpointer;

n=0;
i=0;

//Open directory 
struct dirent *directory;
  ptr = opendir("faketext");
  while((directory = readdir(ptr)) != NULL)
  {
   if ( !strcmp(directory->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(directory->d_name, "..") )
     {

       } else {
    n++;
     }
  }

  rewinddir(ptr);

char *filesList[n];

//Put file names into the array

while((directory = readdir(ptr)) != NULL) {
if ( !strcmp(directory->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(directory->d_name, "..") )
{}
else {
    filesList[i] = (char*) malloc (strlen(directory->d_name)+1);
    strncpy (filesList[i],directory->d_name, strlen(directory->d_name) );
    i++;
}
}
closedir(ptr);

//Open file names from directory, read data, print data to both the terminal and new text file 

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
 char buf[0x100];
 snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "faketext/%s", filesList[i]);
 f = fopen(buf, "r");
 if(f == NULL){
    printf("Trouble opening file.");
   }
 fscanf(f, "%1f", &variable);
 printf("%f\t",variable);

 char buf2[0x100];
 snprintf(buf2, sizeof(buf2), "faketext/%s_data.txt", filesList[i]);
 fpointer = fopen(buf2, "w");
 fprintf(fpointer, "%f", variable);
}


fclose(fpointer);
fclose(f);
return 0;

}
```

This program works beautifully with variable set to integers and floats. However, I'm adapting this program to work with scientific research, and I need the precision of the double. When I read in the files, the code returns 0.000000 for each of the doubles (both in the terminal and the new text file), although the decimals stored in each of the original text files are nonzero.

I've made sure that when I scan in the doubles, the function is set to scan with "%1f" for doubles, as that seems to be the most common error for this kind of thing. 
I'm pretty new to C and have had no formal training in it, so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Many compilers with warnings fully enabled would have warned about `double variable; ...  fscanf(f, "%1f", &variable);`.  Save time, enable all warnings.